# jQuery how to snap to container when reaching the end of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

So this script does what I'm after, only that it doesn't work width a fixed height. It only works with "height: 100%;":

http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/

So what Im really after is a plugin that snaps when reaching the end of the div, so the divs can be any height.

My page's divs is about 2000px each, so when the user reaches the bottom of a div, it snaps to the next section (or to the current if the user didn't scroll down enough), as seen in the plugin.

Thankful for a answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out the [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin.

I changed my demo to snap when the current section reaches the bottom.

You shouldn't snap to the top of current section if the user didn't scroll enough as the section height is large and you wouldn't be able to see the content of that section.

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/T89LF/4/show

http://jsfiddle.net/T89LF/4/

HTML

```
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

jQuery

```
$('section').waypoint(function(direction) { 
    if(direction == 'down'){
        disable_scroll();
        //Animate to top of the section
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        },300,"easeInOutQuart", function() {
           enable_scroll();
        });
    }
}, { offset: '100%' }); 

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function wheel(e) {
  preventDefault(e);
}

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for taking the time to answer. The problem with that solution is that it should snap when scrolling back up, and also snap when being in between two sections, either to the top or bottom, depending on which one is closest, like seen in this screen: http://d.pr/i/uA3F - Try scrolling down to a section that snaps, then scroll back up. It should snap up again. Thanks!

Comment: I did something like that first, http://jsfiddle.net/T89LF/1/show/ but this will snap at any point in the section which would be annoying if you were reading content. So I will need to look at this again.

Comment: I just tried it with different heights... didnt work too good. http://jsfiddle.net/T89LF/7/show/ - the thing that doesnt work is that it should only snap when reach the top/bottom of a section. Say that the offset should be like 500px or something, from the bottom/top. So if I reach the top/bottom of a section and scroll past it less than 500px, it should snap. But when being in the middle of a section, nothing should happen. Think of it like when reaching the bottom, it scrolls to "the next page". Thanks so much for your time once again!

Comment: Kinda like that, except when scrolling to the bottom of a element, it should snap to the bottom of that element. I changes it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/T89LF/11/show/ so when you scroll to the bottom of the first element, and a bit further down, so 20% of the screen is the yellow section and 80% of the screen is the pink section, it should scroll to the bottom of the pink section, and not back to the top. Do you follow what I mean? Thanks again!

Comment: That is right! I changed it a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/T89LF/15/ another question though, that is off-topcix related to this "app". Do you know how I might change the url when entering different sections? Like when scrolling to section 2, the url becomes /#section2 etc? Thanks so much for this - I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: use `window.location.hash = currentSection.attr('id');`
http://jsfiddle.net/T89LF/16/show/